# How should I handle prefer arrow callback and unnamed function code issues

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslintrc

I am new to ES6 and been trying to figure out how to rewrite this.

I am receiving the ff: in my eslint

- Unexpected function expression. (prefer-arrow-callback)
- Unexpected unnamed function. (func-names)

`server.listen(config.site.port, config.site.host, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
     }
    });`

I tried reading the specs and try it out but can't seem to figure out what to do if it has `if` condition.
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And what exactly you don't understand? Sounds very clear English. In any case if you go to eslint website and read `prefer-arrow-callback` and `func-names` it provides example of how it should be to fix it.

Comment: @dfsq having the if statement like how to wrap it. I'm new to this. Like I said I already looked at the specs. Some people are not as bright as you are, my dear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *prefer-arrow-callback* should be fixed by:

```
server.listen(config.site.port, config.site.host, (err) => {
   if (err) {
       throw err;
   }
});
```

Comment: You second snippet is incorrect and will throw error before even executing callback :D

Comment: You updated version is still syntactically incorrect and will throw error. You will not be able to use `&&` operator for shorter syntax.

Comment: @dfsq Ok, I've tested and I see the error but I still don't know why

Comment: `throw err` is a statement while `a && b` is an expression. You cannot use statement inside of an expression. Hence the syntax error.

Comment: @dfsq But why the the short circuit var a = true; var b; a && (b = false) works? b = false isn't statement?

Comment: No, this is assignment expression. Statement does something but does not produce a value necessary for `&&` operator (doesn't "return"). Expression produces a value so it can be part of `&&` expression. So you can do `console.log(b = false)` because it returns result of assignment, but you can't `console.log(throw 123)`.